# Passing enum as function argument (TWAMM)

Tags: anchor, typescript

In the program, `OracleType` enum is defined as

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Debug)]
pub enum OracleType {
    None,
    Test,
    Pyth,
}
```

When I use

```
let tx = await program.methods
        .initTokenPair({
            allowDeposits: false,
            allowWithdrawals: false,
            allowCranks: false,
            allowSettlements: false,
            feeNumerator: new anchor.BN(1),
            feeDenominator: new anchor.BN(10),
            settleFeeNumerator: new anchor.BN(0),
            settleFeeDenominator: new anchor.BN(1),
            crankRewardTokenA: new anchor.BN(2),
            crankRewardTokenB: new anchor.BN(3),
            minSwapAmountTokenA: new anchor.BN(4),
            minSwapAmountTokenB: new anchor.BN(5),
            maxSwapPriceDiff: 0.1,
            maxUnsettledAmount: 0.3,
            minTimeTillExpiration: 0.3,
            maxOraclePriceErrorTokenA: 123.0,
            maxOraclePriceErrorTokenB: 456.0,
            maxOraclePriceAgeSecTokenA: 8,
            maxOraclePriceAgeSecTokenB: 9,
            oracleTypeTokenA: { none: {} },
            oracleTypeTokenB: { none: {} },
            oracleAccountTokenA: PublicKey.default,
            oracleAccountTokenB: PublicKey.default,
            crankAuthority: PublicKey.default,
            timeInForceIntervals: [0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10],
        })
        ....
```

following error log appears

```
Types of property 'oracleTypeTokenA' are incompatible.
        Type '{ none: {}; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.

 60         .initTokenPair({
                           ~
 61             allowDeposits: false,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
... 
 85             timeInForceIntervals: [0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10],
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 86         })
```

Also, TWAMM tag is not available on Stack exchange atm.

Answer (score 1):

I assigned the value to `never` and worked.

```
let nonOracle = { none: {} } as never;
```